# Using Delegates in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to vb.net and trying to build a win CE app in vb.net. The sdk of the handheld device is in C# which I converted with an online converter to vb.net.
Below is the C# code:

```
public class DecodeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string barcode;
    private byte type;

    public DecodeEventArgs(string barcodeData, byte typeData)
    {
        barcode = barcodeData;
        type = typeData;
    }

    public string Barcode
    {
        get { return barcode; }
        set { barcode = value; }
    }

    public byte Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set { type = value; }
    }

}
```

Converted to vb.net as:

```
Public Class DecodeEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Public barcode As String
    Public type As Byte

    Public Sub New(ByVal barcodeData As String, ByVal typeData As Byte)
        barcode = barcodeData
        type = typeData
    End Sub

    Public Property pBarcode() As String
        Get
            Return barcode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            barcode = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property pType() As Byte
        Get
            Return type
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            type = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

In my conversion from C# I added a 'p' to the name of the Properties as you see in my vb.net code because I had a error that said

> Barcode is already declared as a public string in this class

I'm not sure if that is part of my problem but my real issue is, on a form they used .BeginInvoke to call the class with this code:

```
void scanner_DecodeEvent(object sender, DecodeEventArgs e)
    {
        Win32.sndPlaySound(Properties.Resources.Scan, Win32.SND_ASYNC | Win32.SND_MEMORY);

        this.BeginInvoke((Action<string>)delegate(string barcode)
        {
            scanCount = 0;
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { barcode });
            lstView.Items.Insert(0, item);

        }, e.Barcode);
    }
```

Which I converted to vb.net as:

```
Private Sub scanner_DecodeEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DecodeEventArgs)
    PlaySound()

    Me.BeginInvoke(DirectCast(Barcode As String) ) 
    scanCount = 0
    Dim item As New ListViewItem(New String() {barcode})

    lstView.Items.Insert(0, item)


End Sub
```

Which gives me an error about Barcode not being declared. This is where I'm stuck. Thanks for your assistance in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That C# snippet creates an anonymous method which it invokes to perform the actions on the UI thread, and it sends `e.Barcode` as a parameter. Your VB.NET conversion only tries to invoke some strange, and incomplete, use of `DirectCast`. `DirectCast` is not needed in the VB.NET conversion as you don't have any `delegate` keyword which you must cast to a delegate method.

Your most simple solution would be to use a Lambda method:

```
Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() 'Lambda anonymous method.
    scanCount = 0
    Dim item As New ListViewItem(New String() {e.Barcode})
    lstView.Items.Insert(0, item)
End Sub)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since you get errors when using the lambda expression I assume you target .NET Framework 3.5 or lower. For that matter it gets a bit more complicated as you must now put the code in a different method:

```
Private Sub AddBarcode(ByVal Barcode As String)
    scanCount = 0
    Dim item As New ListViewItem(New String() {Barcode})
    lstView.Items.Insert(0, item)
End Sub
```

Then you must declare your own delegate method which you can use to perform the invocation:

```
Delegate Sub AddBarcodeDelegate(ByVal Barcode As String)

Private Sub scanner_DecodeEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DecodeEventArgs)
    Me.BeginInvoke(New AddBarcodeDelegate(AddressOf AddBarcode), e.Barcode)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Visual Vincent. Looks much cleaner now but it underlines Sub(), saying "Expression Expected". I also took out the ")" after "End Sub" because it was underlined too.

Comment: @PercyKumah : What .NET Framework version are you targeting? Also, you don't need to "@" someone on their own post. :)

Comment: The bracket after `End Sub` should be there since it closes `Me.BeginInvoke`.

Comment: Thanks Vincent. I'm targeting 3.5.

Comment: @PercyKumah : Just as I feared. Lambda expressions were added in 4.0. I updated my answer with a solution for 3.5.

Comment: Thanks again. Now AddBarcode is underlined as not declared

Comment: Sorry...please ignore my last comment

Comment: @PercyKumah : Glad I could help! Good luck in the future!